# Proper Meteor error handling with async calls using Future

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, node-fibers

I am wondering how to properly handle errors with Meteor when using async methods. I have tried the following, but the error is being returned in the result parameter on the client callback instead of the error parameter.

Server code:

```
Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

Meteor.methods({
    'myServerMethod': function(){
        var future = new Future();

        // URL to some remote API
        var url = UrlOfTheApiIWantToCall;

        HTTP.get(url, {//other params as a hash},
            function (error, result) {
                if (!error) {
                    future.return(result);
                } else {
                    future.return(error);
                }
            }
        );

        return future.wait();
    }
});
```

Client code:

```
Meteor.call('myServerMethod', function (error, result) {
    if(error){
        console.warn(error);
    }

    console.log('result', result);
});
```

As I was saying above, 'error' is always undefined on the client side event when the HTTP.get() on the server side returned an error. I also tried replacing `future.return(error);` with `future.throw(error);` on the server side, but this really throws an error on the server side. The client side error parameter then gets a 500 Server Error, although the error thrown on the server was a 401 Unauthorized error.

So, is it possible to use Fiber's Future properly so that the client callback receives the same error parameter as the server callback?

Comment: Not the solution but clarification, `HTTP` calls can be synchronous on server side `var res = HTTP.get(url, {})`, there are so many other usecases where we need to use callbacks in server side, I'm looking for a good answer too

Answer (score 4):

According to the `Meteor.Error` docs at http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_error

> Methods can throw any kind of exception. But Meteor.Error is the only kind of error that a server will send to the client. If a method function throws a different exception, then it will be mapped to a sanitized version on the wire. Specifically, if the sanitizedError field on the thrown error is set to a Meteor.Error, then that error will be sent to the client. Otherwise, if no sanitized version is available, the client gets Meteor.Error(500, 'Internal server error').

Which is why you are receiving the `500 Server Error` on the client. If you want to preserve the error message and have it be sent to the client, you can do something like this:

```
Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

Meteor.methods({
    'myServerMethod': function(){
        var future = new Future();

        // URL to some remote API
        var url = UrlOfTheApiIWantToCall;

        HTTP.get(url, {//other params as a hash},
            function (error, result) {
                if (!error) {
                    future.return(result);
                } else {
                    future.throw(error);
                }
            }
        );

        try {
            return future.wait();
        }
        catch(err) {
            // Replace this with whatever you want sent to the client.
            throw new Meteor.Error("http-error", err);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what the try-catch is doing around the future.wait()... Also, I tend to avoid using try-catch blocks in JS because the prevent the whole function from being optimized (see: [https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers)). Do I have to throw an error? All I want to do is report an error to the client side. I find throwing a bit harsh.

Comment: You might be able to replace `future.throw(error)` with `throw new Meteor.Error(..., ...)`